# md-menu md-list-item Angular Material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I want to have a md-menu on a md-2-line list-item directive. note: NOT on the secondary action but primarily on the list item itself. The documentation states that the first element is used as trigger and is left in the DOM, while the second represents the menu contents. So I was surprised that the following structure does not work.

```
<md-list>

    <md-menu>

        <md-list-item class="md-2-line" ng-click="openMenu($mdOpenMenu, $event)" ng-repeat="prop in properties">
            <div class="md-list-item-text">
                <h3>{{ prop['display_name'] }}</h3>
                <p>{{ object[prop.key] }}</p>
            </div>
        </md-list-item>

        <md-menu-content width="6">
            <md-menu-item ng-repeat="val in prop['values']">
                <md-button ng-click="updateAttribute(prop.key, val)">
                    {{val}}
                </md-button>
            </md-menu-item>
        </md-menu-content>

   </md-menu>

</md-list>
```

However, I don't really see what I am doing wrong. I also keep getting the following errors, of which I do not know the meaning:

angular.js:13550 TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasAttribute' of undefined
    at r (http://localhost/flatt.io/app/node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.min.js:13:26527)

and

angular.js:13550 TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at enableHoverListener (angular-material.min.js:13)

Regards

Comment: Could you post this in a code-pen with mocked up data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ng-repeat where prop is defined is on the md-list-item tag. prop falls out of scope when that tag is closed, so it's not available when you go to define your md-menu-content.

Comment: Moving the ng-repeat to the md-menu fixed it, can't believe I missed that. Nice find!